# Merge polygons that are within determined distance

Tags: qgis, merge, attribute-joins, spatial-join, proximity

I have a shapefile containing numerous polygons. I want to merge polygons that have another polygon within a 10 meter distance.

Comment: Which software/tool do you use?

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html

Comment: @BERA DBScan only works for points, I thought?

Comment: In PostGIS you can dbscan polygons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution in QGIS.

**Step 1:** `Buffer` your polygons by 10 m and dissolve while buffering.

**Step 2:** Run `multi to single-part` on your buffers.

**Step 3:** Use `$id` in the field calculator to add a unique ID to your buffers.

**Step 4:** `Join attributes by location` in order to add your buffer-IDs to your original polygons.

**Step 5:** `Dissolve` based on the added IDs.